# Mangle dll exported names with DEF file

Tags: c++, dll, hyperlink, function

I'm trying to create a proxy dll and ran into this issue.
Suppose I have following files:

a.cpp:

```
extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) func(int x) {return x;}
```

a.def:

```
EXPORTS
func
??4Test@@QAEAAU0@ABU0@@Z = func
```

Then I run:

```
cl /c c.cpp
link /RELEASE /DLL /DEF:c.def /OUT:c.dll c.obj
```

Output of `dumpbin /exports c.dll` shows that following symbols are exported:
    func
    ??4Test

Where is the rest of the "Test" exported name? And is there any way to get it back?

Comment: Can't you remove the `extern "C"` and get rid of the .def file? Or is whatever is going to load your DLL expecting a different mangling convention? From what I can tell, I can't make the .def file respect @ signs. Perhaps that's by design.

Comment: I repro.  It is the @ character that's the problem.  It does mean something special in .def files, used to specify the ordinal.  Pretty hard to come up with a workaround for this, other than stopping lying about the method.  Which also prevents you from shooting your leg off, func() is no substitute for an assignment operator.

Comment: Thank you. Then I guess I will try to use WinDbg with custom scripts.

Comment: @EvgenyPakhomov: Did you find a awy around this problem, i.e. did you manage to export symbols with "@" characters? I opened a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106407/is-there-an-alternative-linker-to-link-exe) about this issue, wondering whether there's maybe an alternative linker without this irritating behaviour. Maybe you found something?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a workaround for this. And it appeared that for my task WinDbg was more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot instead, without using a DEF file:

> extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl func(int x) {return x;}

Now it shouldn't mangle the function name at all.

Comment: I think that @Evgeny wants to export a mangled name. Presumably because some other tool is expecting that mangled name.

Comment: @austere I don't see how this helps at all. The OP's signature *already includes* `extern "C"` which prevents name mangling.

Answer (score -1):

One idea which came to my mind: export the symbols using a different placeholder character than "@" (e.g. "^") and then lateron rewrite the export table by treating the DLL as a PE file and rewriting the export table entries on disk.