# Is there an alternative linker to link.exe?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, linker, dllexport

I'm working on a proxy DLL and would like to export symbols with an "@" character in them. However, it appears that this character has a special meaning to link.exe (actually, to lib.exe, I guess?). Given a C++ file

```
extern "C" void f() { }
```

I *can* create a DLL which exports `f` as `foo` by running

```
cl /LD exports.cpp /link /export:foo=f
```

but as soon as the alias contains the "@" character, everything after it (including the "@" itself) appears to get stripped, i.e. all of the following export the same `foo` symbol:

```
cl /LD exports.cpp /link /export:foo=f
cl /LD exports.cpp /link /export:foo@=f
cl /LD exports.cpp /link /export:foo@foo=f
cl /LD exports.cpp /link /export:foo@@foo=f
```

I see that [somebody else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589435/mangle-dll-exported-names-with-def-file) asked about this already; other people confirmed the behaviour, but there was no solution or explanation on what's going on. So I'm wondering:

Is there an alternative (easily accessible) linker for Windows which lets me export symbols with arbitrary names?

Comment: Could this be related to name mangling?

Comment: Isn't the problem simply that, under Windows, '@' is considered to be a separator in name mangling?

Comment: @kfsone Is there some convention or requirement in the PE-COFF spec that says `@` is a separator in the export listing? I always thought that this was implementation defined -- the tool itself can use any kind of encoding it wants.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I suspect it is indeed related to the MSVC name mangling, but I find it surprising that the linker cares about name mangling - I'd have thought it just sees a flat list of symbols. For what it's worth, you *can* have a COFF object with a symbol involving '@@' by writing a simple assembler program. So if there is some restriction, it appears to only apply to the export list - which doesn't make it any less mysterious.

Comment: _Which_ link.exe are we talking about? Probably the MSVC link.exe? Bceuase it's not at all weird that MSVC cares about MSVC conventions.

Comment: @MSalters: It's `link.exe` shipped with MSVC, yes - I think it's weird because I used the linker for linking objects created from a wide variety of assemblers (mostly different compilers) and never noticed what seems to be an assumption on the `link.exe` side. For what it's worth, I just noticed that other microsoft tools (e.g. the Macro Assembler `ml.exe`) can be told to use a different linker than  `link.exe` as well. So I don't think the toolchain is *that* tightly coupled.