# Why microsoft linker modifies decorated export names?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dllexport, name-decoration

I'm trying to make a proxy dll using the "wrappit" tool as recommended [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16541/Create-your-Proxy-DLLs-automatically). The tools "wrappit" creates as .cpp correctly:

```
// ??0CFileFormat@@QAE@XZ
extern "C" __declspec(naked) void __stdcall __E__0__()
    {
    __asm
        {
        jmp p[0*4];
        }
    }

// ?GetSkipListingForSPlanner@EnvironVar@@SAKXZ
extern "C" __declspec(naked) void __stdcall __E__262__()
    {
    __asm
        {
        jmp p[262*4];
        }
    }
```

as accompanying .def file:

```
EXPORTS
??0CFileFormat@@QAE@XZ=__E__0__ @1
?GetSkipListingForSPlanner@EnvironVar@@SAKXZ=__E__262__ @263
```

But after I have built the resulting library, all the names of the exported functions in the dll built appear to be truncated right as the description of the parameters begins. So `??0CFileFormat@@QAE@XZ` turns in `??0CFileFormat`, `?GetSkipListingForSPlanner@EnvironVar@@SAKXZ` turns into `?GetSkipListingForSPlanner@EnvironVar` and so on. As a result, my proxy dll does not load due to the lack of necessary exports. Why this happens and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Remember that C++ does *NOT* have a stable ABI. *Everything* that is part of your program; executable, libraries etc, *all* need to be built with the *same* compiler / tool-chain.

Comment: The @ character in a .def file has a dedicated use, it marks the ordinal of an exported function.  That makes uses mangled names in a .def file [rather unpractical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589435/mangle-dll-exported-names-with-def-file).  A possible workaround is to not use a .def file but embed #pragma linker("/export:foo=bar") in the source code.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, I know about the same compiler/toolchain requiriments. So I use _right_ _same_ compiler/toolchain to build my proxy dll which were used to build the original one.

Comment: @HansPassant, I know about ordinals and @ character. The @ character marks an ordinal if it is _starts_ number, f.e. ```my_ord_one_func @1``` in the definition file. In my case the linker just discards anything after the @ character even in the middle word not in the beginning.

Comment: And yes. ```#pragma linker("/export:foo=bar")``` does not work, the linker complains that ```bar``` is missing and cannot be resolved. The ```#pragma comment``` I used as my very first resort and went down to module definition file failed to get around with ```#pragma comment```.

Comment: I wonder if the linker is using the type info from the _internal name_?  Or does it not handle aliasing mangled names?  The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/exports?view=vs-2019) doesn't address this.  So I did some experimenting, and it seems the alias name gets mangled _after_ the name is resolved, so a leading underscore was added, and `@4` for parameter length got added for __stdcall functions.  I didn't lose any of the C++ mangled name, though, although since additional mangling was added it may not be useful (VS2019).

Comment: @HansPassant, I tried as @FrerichRaabe proposes here: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589435/mangle-dll-exported-names-with-def-file) and temporary export the symbols using a different placeholder. I used '~' and '^' instead of '@'. The symbols are exported Ok, I can then load and run functions named ```??0CFileFormat~~QAE~XZ``` instead of ```??0CFileFormat@@QAE@XZ``` but after I have changed '~' back to '@' I get ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND when loading some functions (the other functions are loaded Ok) with GetProcAddres. Why this should happen?